How to generate a series but keep the start and end date?
Edited* Using psql 9.4.26
I have this table:



Key
Start
End




ABC123
24/01/2012
23/01/2013



And using psql, I'm trying to get an output similar to:



Key
Start
End




ABC123
24/01/2012
31/01/2012


ABC123
1/02/2012
29/02/2012


ABC123
1/03/2012
31/03/2012


ABC123
1/04/2012
30/04/2012


ABC123
1/05/2012
31/05/2012


ABC123
1/06/2012
30/06/2012


ABC123
1/02/2012
31/07/2012


ABC123
1/08/2012
31/08/2012


ABC123
1/09/2012
30/09/2012


ABC123
1/10/2012
31/10/2012


ABC123
1/11/2012
30/11/2012


ABC123
1/12/2012
31/12/2012


ABC123
1/01/2013
23/01/2013



I queried the following:
WITH date_ranges AS (
    SELECT
        TO_DATE("Start", 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS start_date,
        TO_DATE("End", 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS end_date
    FROM
      tabl
)
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(month_start, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS Start,
    TO_CHAR(LEAST(month_start + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', end_date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS End
FROM
    date_ranges
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(
    date_trunc('month', start_date),
    LEAST(date_trunc('month', end_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' - INTERVAL '1 day', end_date),
    INTERVAL '1 month'
) AS month_start(month_start);

However, the first record output is this:



Key
Start
End




ABC123
1/01/2012
31/01/2012



The outcome should be:



Key
Start
End




ABC123
24/01/2012
31/01/2012




using psql 9.4.26

The Postgresql version is of much more importance.

simple change in TO_CHAR(greatest(start_date,month_start), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS Start

Offtopic: You are aware that version 9.4 is EOL since 2020?


The same way you're picking the end by taking least("End",output_of_gen_series) - because for the entire period except the very end, it'll be greater - you can pick greatest("Start",output_of_gen_series): at the beginning of the range "Start" will be greater, then smaller for the rest of the period.
You don't need the precise end in generate_series(): it's checking each generated value against the upper limit.
You can merge interval expressions interval '1 month' - interval '1 day' into a single interval '1 month - 1 day'.

Demo at db<>fiddle (version 9.4.26):
select to_char( greatest( to_date("Start", 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                         ,date_step)
               ,'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Start"
      ,to_char( least( to_date("End", 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                      ,date_step+'1 month -1 day'::interval)
               ,'DD/MM/YYYY') as "End"
from tabl cross join lateral 
generate_series( date_trunc('month', to_date("Start",'DD/MM/YYYY'))
                ,to_date("End",'DD/MM/YYYY')
                ,'1 month'::interval) as date_step;




Start
End




24/01/2012
31/01/2012


01/02/2012
29/02/2012


01/03/2012
31/03/2012


01/04/2012
30/04/2012


01/05/2012
31/05/2012


01/06/2012
30/06/2012


01/07/2012
31/07/2012


01/08/2012
31/08/2012


01/09/2012
30/09/2012


01/10/2012
31/10/2012


01/11/2012
30/11/2012


01/12/2012
31/12/2012


01/01/2013
23/01/2013



